# Civilization: game in real time with 10 players

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-6

I would like to play civilization with 8 to 10 friends in multiplayer.

We are currently playing on the V and it appears that with more than 6 players it is not possible to play (people are disconnected / they cannot join / whatever).

More  precisely for the people that have problem, they suddenly see everyone else than them disconnected from the game. I insist on the fact that those player don't have problem with their computer as it is possible to play with them with fewer players. Furthermore it is not like there is some specific player that have this problem, whenever we are more than 6 some players will face it.

I also have notice that many people face the same problem around more than 7 players.

I would like to know if there is a way to play on civilization V allowing to be around 10 to play **simultaneously**.

I have read few things about dedicated servers: would this fix the problem ?

In civilization 6, how many maximum online player it is possible to play without having bugs like I explained ?

Answer (score 2):

Well if they don't block you at 6 means that it's supposed to work at the 10 you can get in the lobby.

So at the end of the day, it might be the hosting person that is the problem, or the connecting pcs. At that point I can't really help you.

For dedicated servers, maybe. If it hosts the game elsewhere there should be less problems for the one that used to host, but I don't know if it will work.

Here's my tip. If it's always the same 2-3 people that DC/Cant join, they should be getting error codes. Google them, they will have some info on that. It could just be they all have the same firewall that for some reason doesn't want to let your connexion through.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Civilization 5 is known to be quite buggy on multiplayer. This was the purpose of my question: are there trick to make it less buggy (like unknown patch from the community, or dedicated server etc). Furthermore they do not have error message, they are just disconnected from the lobby.

Comment: To be more accurate I added a paragraph describing their exact problem.

Comment: At that point, I have sadly no idea. When I play with friends we play with 4 players.